# Brach URL is giving "Trouble creating a URL" when tracking is disabled and trying to create a short url

Tags: branch.io

For GDPR compliance reasons, we have disabled link tracking in our Android and iOS applications and using generate Short URL method for getting the short link of the item, we want to share. But when we are calling generateShortUrl() method, it gives "Trouble creating a URL. Tracking is disabled. Requested operation cannot be completed when tracking is disabled" error and the URL that is returned does not work when shared on Facebook or an email when the user clicks on it.

Our concern is though tracking is disabled and Branch is unable to create a short URL, it shall return the working long URL at least. Please let us know if we have to do something here to make it work on our apps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you set `generateShortUrl` like the following example codes for Android? You can also find detailed information about creating deep link

- Android : https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/#create-deep-link
- iOS : https://docs.branch.io/apps/ios/#create-deep-link

.

```
import io.branch.indexing.BranchUniversalObject;
import io.branch.referral.Branch;
import io.branch.referral.BranchError;
import io.branch.referral.util.LinkProperties;

BranchUniversalObject buo = new BranchUniversalObject();
LinkProperties lp = new LinkProperties();


buo.generateShortUrl(this, lp, new Branch.BranchLinkCreateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
        if (error == null) {
            Log.i("BRANCH SDK", "got my Branch link to share: " + url);
        }
    }
});
```

Also, if you have any further questions, please contact [support@branch.io](http://support@branch.io) to give better assistance.